# pull repository from Jenkins to Github or Gitlab

Tags: git, jenkins, devops

I installed Jenkins, git_client and git_server using vagrant CLI. I created 3 projects in Jenkins which I want to push to Gitlab. How is this possible through command line?

Thanks.

Comment: You want to push changes to github after jenkins build completes? Or just simple push projects to github ?

Comment: Hi, I want to simply push projects to GitHub from Jenkins

Answer (score 0):

You can follow [this tutorial](http://www.nailedtothex.org/roller/kyle/entry/configuring-automatic-push-by-successfully) which will

- declare and use a bare repo (you can push to that bare repo)
- build the bare repo checked out by the Jenkins job
- if the build is successful, it will push it through a Git Publisher step of the [Jenkins Git Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin)

In your case, you need to create a repo on GitLab or GitHub, and use that url in your Job.
Associate it with the right credential with the [Jenkins Credential Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Plugin) (like your GitHUb username/password, if you don't have activated 2FA -- two factor authentication)

The key to your question is:

> Add post-build action ⇒ Git Publisher, and check "Push only if build succeeds"

[image: http://www.nailedtothex.org/roller/kyle/mediaresource/44eeab12-4cf2-4c4a-81a9-785b99514659]

Those two options will ensure that, when you trigger this job.

Comment: Thanks for the info. In the post build action, what should I put in the place of  branch to push and target remote name fields?

Comment: @Yashaswini 'master' for the branch (it usually is) and 'origin' for target remote name.

Comment: I did as u said and build the project but I am getting the error below.    Build step 'Git Publisher' marked build as failure
Warning: you have no plugins providing access control for builds, so falling back to legacy behavior of permitting any downstream builds to be triggered
Finished: FAILURE

Comment: @Yashaswini Check out https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/209641937-How-to-configure-Access-Control-for-Builds, and the https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Authorize+Project+plugin